# Joining the values of keys in array - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am noob in ruby and have an array of hashes as per below. Say my array is @fruits_list:

```
[
    {:key_1=>15, :key_2=>"Apple"}, 
    {:key_1=>16, :key_2 =>"Orange"}, 
    {:key_1=>17, :key_2 =>"Cherry"}
]
```

What I am looking for is to join the names of the fruits. I did `@fruits_list[:key_2].join('|')`

and I am getting the error as `"TypeError:no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-collect) first to collect names of fruits, then join them with a pipe `|` using [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
@fruits_list = [
                  {:key_1=>15, :key_2=>"Apple"}, 
                  {:key_1=>16, :key_2 =>"Orange"}, 
                  {:key_1=>17, :key_2 =>"Cherry"}
               ]
@fruits_list.collect { |hsh| hsh[:key_2] }.join("|")
# => "Apple|Orange|Cherry"
```

`@fruits_list` is an array of hash(s). Elements of an array [can be accessed via the integer indexes only](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements). But you tried to access it with a symbol `:key_2`, thus it raised an error as *"TypeError:no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"*.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Looking at the error I understood what the issue was but wasn't able to get through the solution. Another method I tried was getting each object out of the array and then doing a join on it which was again incorrect because I was trying to join value of :key_2 of one object but the other object was not ready yet. Anyways this helped a lot!! Thanks!!

Comment: My requirement on this has changed a bit. I am now checking if the value is nil, then I wouldn't be including it in the list or collect. Eg: In the example in your reply, say {:key_1=>17, :key_2 => " "}; then I wouldn't include this in my list. My final list should be {"Apple" | "Orange"} and not {"Apple" | "Orange" | " "}. I tried this, @fruits_list.collect { |hsh| hsh[:key_2] unless hsh[:key_2].nil? }.join("|") but its still returning the nil value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: oh okay. I will do that. Since it was related to this, I added it here.

Comment: I created it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716604/checking-for-nil-value-inside-collect-function