# Checking for nil value inside collect function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collect

I have an array of hashes as per below. Say my array is @fruits_list:

```
[
    {:key_1=>15, :key_2=>"Apple"}, 
    {:key_1=>16, :key_2 =>"Orange"}, 
    {:key_1=>17, :key_2 =>" "}
]
```

I want to join the values in the hash using a '|'; but my final output should not contain the nil value. I connect it using:

```
@fruits_list.collect { |hsh| hsh[:key_2] }.join("|")
```

But this adds nil in my output, so my final output has 3 items {"Apple" | "Orange" | " "}. I want 2 items in my list and would like to eliminate the nil value, so my final output should look like {"Apple" | "Orange"}.

I tried: `@fruits_list.collect { |hsh| hsh[:key_2] unless hsh[:key_2].nil? }.join("|")` but even this returns me 3 items in the final output. What am I doing wrong or how can I eliminate the nil value?

Comment: Thats not a `nil` value, its a `space`

Comment: unless hsh[:key_2].blank? will do what you want.  As Bala says nil won't work

Answer (score 3):

You can filter on non-blank values using:

```
a.collect{ |h| h[:key_2] }.select(&:present?).join('|')
```

The [`present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method returns `true` only if the thing is sufficiently "non-blank", that is empty string, string composed of spaces, empty array, empty hash are all considered blank.

Comment: In ruby we can not use present? method with string.

Comment: @AlokAnand The question is tagged with Ruby on Rails, so `present?` should be defined as it's part of ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [
    {:key_1=>15, :key_2=>"Apple"}, 
    {:key_1=>16, :key_2 =>"Orange"}, 
    {:key_1=>17, :key_2 =>" "}
]

a.collect{ |hsh| hsh[:key_2] unless hsh[:key_2] =~ /\s+/}.compact.join("|")

#=> "Apple|Orange"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Tried this. I am not getting anything in the output.